# ArcGIS 10: How to programatically project coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

Let's say I have coordinates defined for SRID 4686, is there a way to programatically transform them to SRID 4682?

Comment: In Python, ModelBuilder, or...?

Comment: i would like to know about all the available options.

Comment: That's a bit broad in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the [Project Geoprocessing Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000) is all you'd need. If you don't want a permanently saved projected dataset you could write to `in_memory`. In Python, if you set the output featureset to `arcpy.Geometry()` you can use `result.getOutput(0)` to get a simple projected Geometry object back.